# Using preg_match()

Tags: php, regex

Only binary digits upto 8 digits

```
(preg_match("/^[0-1]{1,8}$/", $binary)
```

How to make a preg_match() that is upto 11 digits only that starts only with 09 and 63?

```
(preg_match('/^[!{09}|{63}]/', $mobile)
```

Problem is only 09 and 63 should start first, and do not exceed at 11 digits.

Comment: Please clarify which digits follow 09|63. Binary set or decimal set?

Answer (score 1):

`/^(09|63)[\d]{9}$/m`

Tested with:

```
09999999999 => pass
63999999999 => pass
11999999999 => fail
63aaaaaaaaa => fail
09bbbbbbbbb => fail
```

http://regex101.com/r/kM8kF9

Comment: In this case, there's no need to enclose `\d` into square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
preg_match("/^(?:63|09)[0-1]{0,8}$/", $binary)
```

Comment: `[0-1]` == `[01]`, one character less !

Comment: I initially wrote `[0-9]` and later edited the code and hence the mess!! :-P... Thanks!